# Youtube: Increase page load speed (Greasemonkey/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, youtube, greasemonkey

It's certainly noticeable how delayed a YouTube video page can load when on a slower computer or laptop. Things such as the sidebar, comments, the uploaders Icon and other image elements. My script will allow you to click certain parts of the page to load these elements on demand. Customize it as you will.

Using:

- Firefox 33.0.3
- Greasemonkey 2.3

---

1. Clicking the title under the video, loads the video.
2. Clicking anywhere in the top header loads the sidebar, uploader Icon, comments, and header contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Youtube: Page load performace
// @namespace     computerarea / twitter
// @description   hide / shows elements to increase page load time
// @include       https://www.youtube.com/watch?*
// @version       1
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

///*Hides by defualt*///
    $('#watch-discussion').hide(0);
    $('#yt-masthead').hide(0);
    $('.yt-user-photo.g-hovercard').hide(0);
    $('#watch7-sidebar-contents').hide(0);
    $('#footer-container').hide(0);
    $('#player-api').hide(0);

///*Actions that change defualts*///
$("#masthead-positioner").click(function(){
    $('#yt-masthead').delay(500).show(0);
    $('.yt-user-photo.g-hovercard').delay(500).show(0);
    $('#watch7-sidebar-contents').delay(500).show(0);
    $('#footer-container').delay(500).show(0);
    $('#watch-discussion').delay(500).show(0);
});
$("#eow-title").click(function(){
    $('#player-api').delay(500).show(0);
});

///*DO NOT TOUCH*///
var script = unsafeWindow.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    unsafeWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener('load', function(){ 
        jQuery = unsafeWindow['jQuery'];
        unsafeWindow['$_'] = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    }, false);
```